# NameError: name 'FileAttachment' is not defined

Tags: python, django, generics, django-models

I have two different Django Apps, one of them is `fileUpload`. In File Upload I added a Generic Relation as:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class FileAttachment(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='fileuploads/%Y-%m-%d/')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    attachee = generic.GenericForeignKey()
```

In my other app named `XYZ` I added following reverse generic relation in `models.py`

```
attachment = generic.GenericRelation(FileAttachment)
```

Now, so if I run `manage.py syncdb` or any other manage command, I get error: **NameError: FileAttachment**

IN installed Apps I have following stuff:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.markup',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'south',
    'taggit',
    'taggit_autocomplete_modified',
    'compressor',
    'bootstrapform',
    'fileupload',
    'XYZ'
)
```

Both apps, `XYZ` and `fileupload` are on same root level.

I am using Django 1.5 with Python2.7

Comment: have you imported `FileAttachment` in the `XYZ/models.py` file? something like `from fileUpload.models import FileAttachment`

Answer (score 2):

Did you import the FileAttachement in the XYZ models?

Try this in **XYZ/models.py**:

`from fileupload.models import FileAttachment`

Comment: It did not work. What I guess it is not working because of PATH issue as INSTALLED_APPS see in PYTHONPATH only?

Comment: I just pasted the line you write and I get following now: ** from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ortError: No module named django.core.management**  I am using *VirtualEnv*

Comment: Ok, in *PyCharm* IDE there is option of **Django Console** in that console I am able to import properly. What I guess init.py needs to include my directory as PATH? am I right?